# Using custom keras model with layer sharing together dqn_agent.DqnAgent()

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I am trying to use a custom neural network with the DqnAgent() from tf. In my model **I need to use layer sharing**. Thus, I use the functional API to build the model. The model has a dict as input and one layer with n neurons as output. The last layer is a Concat- and not a Dens-Layer though. The type of the model that i get from the functional API `keras.Model(inputs=[...], outpunts[...]`
is "keras.engine.functional.Functional".

Now i want to use my Model with the tf Agent like this:

```
agent = dqn_agent.DqnAgent(
    train_env.time_step_spec(),
    train_env.action_spec(),
    q_network=model,
    optimizer=optimizer,
    td_errors_loss_fn=common.element_wise_squared_loss,
    train_step_counter=train_step_counter)
```

I get the following Error thoug:

```
AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute 'create_variables'
  In call to configurable 'DqnAgent' (<class 'tf_agents.agents.dqn.dqn_agent.DqnAgent'>)
```

The q_network expects a network from type "network.Network". I am not sure how to convert or wrap my environment in such a way, that the DqnAgent() will accept it. How could I manage to do this? Any support is much appreciated. If you need more information about anything let me know.

Additional information about my Network:

- Input dict with multiple inputs.
- multiple shared dens layers. output of the last one is shape (1,).
- concatenate all those outputs of shape (1,)
- one multipy layer to eliminate infeasible actions by multiplying the outputs with 0 or 1 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: before the `agent = dqn_agent.DqnAgent...` bit, redefine `model` by adding this in:

```
model = tf_agents.networks.sequential.Sequential(model.layers)
```

This:

- pulls out all the layers from the original network using `model.layers`,
- then builds a new network of the `tf_agents.networks.sequential.Sequential` type using those same layers.

Hopefully the new model should work for your DQN.